# Chrome jquery css strange checkbox behavior

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, css

I think I've got a chrome related bug and the strange thing is, it suddenly happened without changing my code. I've made a script that remembers the selected checkbox value with jquery cookie. This works but for some reason there are problems with the css. In chrome when I reload the checkboxes are checked wrong until I hover over them. I'm using Chrome Version 25.0.1364.45 beta. I'm suspecting the label:after selector not working properly. Safari or firefox do not have this behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/S2YVu/4/

EDIT: okay I think there is something going wrong on the line:
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after

Is anyone familiar with CSS3 selector problems in chrome?

css:

```
.selectbox {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.selectbox input[type="checkbox"] {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.selectbox label {
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    top: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    text-indent: 30px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-family: @serif;
    font-style: italic;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    line-height: 17px;
}

.selectbox label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 6px;
    height: 4px;
    background: transparent;
    top: 2px;
    left: 3px;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.selectbox label:hover::after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.selectbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing this problem in 24.0.1312.56. Unless I'm missing something. Do you have a before and after screenshot of the issue?

Comment: He thanks for the reply. It's hard to explain, image: http://img26.imageshack.us/img26/9256/hoverbug.png . What basically happens is. 1: all the checkboxes look checked (so the css that lets the label look like it's checked is applied) and when I hover over them the ones that are actually checked stay checked and the ones that are not checked, 'uncheck'. 2: the opposite happens, the first one is checked and the rest isn't until I hover over them and the ones that should be checked become checked. I did not have the time to check it on another copy of chrome 25, but at 24 it did not occur